# pynacl crypto_core_hsalsa20 for nuki smartlock 2.0

Tags: python-3.x, hash, nacl-cryptography, pynacl, kdf

I need the crypto_core_hsalsa20 function to greate an secret key for my [NUKI](https://developer.nuki.io/t/bluetooth-api/27).

> Both sides calculate DH Key k using function dh1
> a. Key
> 0DE40B998E0E330376F2D2FC4892A6931E25055FD09F054F99E93FECD9BA611E
> 8. Both sides derive a long term shared secret key s from k using function kdf1
> a. Shared key
> 217FCB0F18CAF284E9BDEA0B94B83B8D10867ED706BFDEDBD2381F4CB3B8F730

> 4.2 The key derivation function kdf1

```
static const unsigned char _0[16];
static const unsigned char sigma[16] = "expand 32-byte k";
crypto_core_hsalsa20(k,_0,s,sigma)
```

> Used to derive a long term secret key out of the shared key calculated by dh1

I alredy calculated the DH Key k with the nacl.publik.Box (=dh1) function.

Can someone tell me how to use the kdf1 function with pynacl?
Thanks!